Rotate coordinaten system with PGFPlots
I want to rotate a coordinate system with pgf-plots using rotate around={angle:point}. I would expect to use (0,0) but using trial and error I found rotate around={30:(170,-220)}. Can somebody explain this behavior? How can I find the exact value?
Here my MWE

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,font= \footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle,xlabel = {$x$},ylabel = {$y$},samples=100,grid=both,xmin=-2.3,xmax=2.3,ymin=-0.3, ymax=5.3,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\addplot[very thick,blue,domain=-2:3,rotate around={30:(0,0)}] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle,xlabel = {$w$},ylabel = {$z$},samples=100,grid=both,xmin=-2.3,xmax=2.3,ymin=-0.3, ymax=2.3,x=1cm,y=1cm,red,thick,rotate around={30:(170,-220)}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


You can use (axis cs:0,0) or (current axis.origin) (the axis coordinates are not the default coordinate system before inside axis).
The easiest way to make the origins coincide is to insert both axis relative to their origin with anchor=origin like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
anchor=origin,
axis lines=middle,
x=1cm, y=1cm,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
grid=both,
xmin=-2.3, xmax=2.3,
ymin=-0.3, ymax=5.3,
]
\addplot[very thick, blue, domain=-2:2, samples=100, rotate around={30:(0,0)}] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
red, thick,
anchor=origin,
axis lines=middle,
x=1cm, y=1cm,
rotate around={30:(current axis.origin)},
xlabel={$w$}, ylabel={$z$},
grid=both,
xmin=-2.3, xmax=2.3,
ymin=-0.3, ymax=2.3,
]
\addplot[very thick, cyan, domain=-2:2, samples=100] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


